# Magento 2 : Instagram Graph API Integration

Tags: magento2, api, instagram

Instagram now updated its API and now it uses Facebook Graph API. I want to get all the images from my Instagram page in Magento 2.

How can I retrieve it in Magento 2?

It always return :

> **The access_token provided is invalid.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really a Magento 2 specific question, should be split into an Instagram (how do I access instagram api) and Magento 2 (how do I do whatever you want to do with the images) questions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But, I know very well it's Magento related question or not. I am trying to integrate in Magento store. I also added API code. But, something is wrong in access_token as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get public posts Data JSON by hashtag using below URL.

> https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/<Hashtag>/?__a=1

one of the example URL is https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/tranding/?__a=1

You can get response in JSON format then you can process it and do whatever you want to do.
Weather you can save the data to your database as well as you can only display the data on frontend.

Thank You.

Comment: It's not seems that is api url.